# Template specialization and derived classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have this simple code:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};
class C : public B{};

class Test
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        void f(T&){printf("template\n");}
        void f(A&){printf("specialization\n");}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    Test test;
    test.f(a);
    test.f(b);
    test.f(c);
}
```

When I run it(VS2010) I have this output:

```
specialization
template
template
```

Is it possible to make the calls with `A-derived` classes to use specialization?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The question is totaly ambiguous

Comment: @Desolator He means he wants anything that derives from A as well as A instances themselves to use the override to an A-reference rather than the  generic template expansion. His calls to use `foo()`  with `B` and `C` instances are using the generic, not the override.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! This is exactly what I want. A-derived classes have a function that I need to call. The other types don't have this function and I need to use traits instead.

Comment: @Felics you should probably know this right now. That "specialization" isn't. Its an overload. There is a *world* of difference.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, you are right, but in my case the behavior is the same:)

Comment: @Felics See Andy's answer. It is going to get you near-exactly what you need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to change your code a bit.

First of all, to be technical, the second function `f()` is **not** a specialization of the template function, but an **overload**. When resolving overload, the template version is chosen for all arguments whose type is not `A`, because it is a perfect match: `T` is deduced to be equal to the type of the argument, so when calling `f(b)`, for instance, after type deduction the compiler will have to choose between the following two overloads:

```
void f(B&){printf("template\n");}
void f(A&){printf("specialization\n");}
```

Of course, the first one is a better match.

Now if you want the second version to be selected when the function is invoked with an argument which is a subclass of `A`, you have to use some SFINAE technique to prevent the function template from being correctly instantiated when the type `T` is deduced to be a subclass of `A`.

You can use `std::enable_if` in combination with the `std::is_base_of` type traits to achieve that.

```
// This will get instantiated only for those T which are not derived from A
template<typename T,
    typename enable_if<
        !is_base_of<A, T>::value
        >::type* = nullptr
    >
void f(T&) { cout << "template" << endl; }
```

Here is how you would use it in a complete program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{};
class B : public A{};
class C : public B{};
class D {};

class Test
{
    public:

        template<typename T,
            typename enable_if<!is_base_of<A, T>::value>::type* = nullptr
            >
        void f(T&) { cout << ("template\n"); }

        void f(A&){ cout << ("non-template\n");}

};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    float f;

    Test test;
    test.f(a); // Will print "non-template"
    test.f(b); // Will print "non-template"
    test.f(c); // Will print "non-template"
    test.f(d); // Will print "template"
    test.f(f); // Will print "template"
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you are working with a compiler which is not fully compliant with C++11 (and therefore does not support default template arguments on function templates), you might want to change the definition of your template overload of `f()` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_base_of<A, T>::value, void>::type 
f(T&) { cout << ("template\n"); }
```

The behavior of the program will be identical. Note that if the return type of `f()` is `void`, you can omit the second argument to the `enable_if` class template.

Comment: +1 to you Andy. I was about to start typing up the SFINAE answer to this, thanks for saving me the keystrokes =)

Comment: Note: the `p` name is optional in the template parameter list.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Correct. I'll remove it

Comment: @AndyProwl Thanks for help. Unfortunately this is not compiling in VS2010: error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template

Comment: @Felics: I see. That's because VC10 is not fully compliant with C++11. However, there is a way to work around that. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @AndyProwl I have another way too... But the compiler crashes:))

Comment: @Felics: Done. Check out if the version I added works for you

Comment: @AndyProwl Thanks, it works. I used similar thing, but as additional parameter instead of return type and the compiler crashed.