# C++ templated function overloading rules

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

When overloading a templated function, how should the compiler chose which version of the function to call if it has the option to either:

- Call a templated version of the function (such as `func<T>(foo)`).
- Call an overloaded version of the function which is not itself templated but where the type of the parameter being passed to the function inherits from the type specified in the overloaded function template.

Consider the following C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Parent {}; 
struct Child : public Parent {}; 

template <typename T>
void func(T) {
  printf("func(T)\n");
}

void func(Parent) {
  printf("func(Parent)\n");
}

int main() {
  func(1);
  func(Parent());
  func(Child());
}
```

Compiled with gcc or clang, this outputs:

```
func(T)
func(Parent)
func(T)
```

The first two lines are expected and make sense. However, in the call `func(Child())`, it could just as easily call `func(Parent)` (which seems like, if anything, what it *should* do).

As such, I have two main questions:

- What are the exact rules laid out by the standard as to how to resolve such conflicts? There is some information [in this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411482/c-template-functions-overload-resolution), but if anything it conflicts with what I am observing.
- Is there any way to force the compiler to call `func(Parent)` when passed a `Child`?

I can get around this requirement in my own code and this example is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, but I believe that it is the same problem.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797303/template-specialization-and-derived-classes-in-c for the second part of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for overload resolution go something like this:

1. Find all the candidate functions by name
2. Perform template deduction and prune down to the viable candidates (i.e. drop the calls that are ill-formed).
3. Pick the best viable candidate via:

   a. Choose the one with the best conversion sequence   (think of this as "doing the least necessary work to convert from the argument types to the parameter types")
    b. Choose the non-function template over the function template
    c. Choose the most specialized function template

Let's go into these on a case by case basis. For your function calls:

```
func(1);
```

After (2), we have one viable candidate, `func<int>`. `func(Parent )` is not a viable candidate, since `Parent` is not constructible from `int`, so we're done and call the function template.

```
func(Parent());
```

We have two viable candidates: `func<Parent>` and `func(Parent )`. Both take the exact same arguments so the conversion sequences are identical. So we end up in step 3b: we choose the non-template over the template, and we call `func(Parent )`.

```
func(Child());
```

We have two viable candidates: `func<Child>` and `func(Parent )`. In the former case, the argument type is `Child` so it's an *exact match* for what we're passing in (no conversion necessary). In the latter case, the argument type is `Parent` so we'd have to perform a derived-to-base conversion. Since the function template has a better conversion sequence (i.e. no conversion necessary), it is considered the best viable overload. You *could* call `func(Parent )` - that is a *viable* candidate, but it's not the *best* viable candidate. `func<Child>` is a better match.

> Is there any way to force the compiler to call `func(Parent)` when passed a `Child`?

You could either cast the `Child` to a `Parent` yourself:

```
Child c;
func(static_cast<Parent>(c));
```

Or you could write another overload that takes a `Child`, which would be preferred only in the 3rd case (and only viable in the 3rd case):

```
void func(Child );
```

Or rewrite your function template so as to not take any class in that hierarchy:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              !std::is_convertible<T*, Parent*>::value
          >>
void func(T );
```

The latter solution (called SFINAE) would remove `func<Child>` from the set of viable candidates, so that the only viable candidate becomes `func(Parent )`.

Comment: `func (Parent)` is not a viable candidate for (3), otherwise it would have been prefered to the template function.

Comment: @AlexandreC. It is absolutely a viable candidate. `Child` is convertible to `Parent`. It's just a worse match.

Comment: My bad. I always thought that non-templates were always preferred to templates, but it turns out that it is not always the case. It depends (quite subtly) on what is considered a "better" conversion sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to get anything done, the standard invented a list of goodness, and the order in which different things would be tried.  There are series of lectures on C9 from STL that go into this in length.

First, the template instantiates a solution for each of the three cases.
The second version picks `func(Parent)` because it matches exactly, and wins over the template.  The third call takes the templated version over a conversion which is considered "less good".

My only thought on preventing this would be to do some horrible SFINAE that tests for every T that it can't be inherited from `Parent` using type traits.  Concepts in C++17 might allow for something slightly less convoluted.

See

[Stephan T. Lavavej: Core C++, 2 of n - Template Argument Deduction](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-2-of-n)

[Stephan T. Lavavej: Core C++, 3 of n - Overload Resolution](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n)

Comment: Okay; that's basically what I was expecting. Do you happen to have links to any of these lectures or anything that goes into more detail about this?

Comment: "an overload wins over a template." They're both overloads, so this isn't quite what you mean...

Comment: "The third call takes the templated version over a conversion which is more of a last resort." Conversion sequence is the *first* resort, not the last resort.